# Teclado numérico no IOS

Tags: objective-c

Estou começando a programar e tenho umas perguntas de noob :) queria saber como que faço em uma UITextField subir automáticamente o teclado numérico?

Ja tentei usar o keyboardType mas não sei exatamente como aplicar as propriedades

Obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá uma olhada nesse vídeo, sei que está inglês mas é só seguir os passos que ele mostra que vai deve fazer o que você precisa.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNCVmkv_vdI

Valeu

Comment: se você puder descrever a solução apresentada no vídeo, vai ajudar qualquer outra pessoas no futuro que venha nesta mesma pergutna (e só saiba falar portugues)

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem a duvida, mas não seria só alterar diretamente no storyboard?

Caso queira uma forma de alterar durante o programa:

`[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];`

Espero ter entendido e ajudado! rs